# Can/should I explicitly require DOM globals like window in AMD modules?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm building my first major project with AMD modules - it's a client-side project, and I'm using require.js to load modules on-the-fly.

I'm very happy with the idea of having to explicitly import the dependencies of each module, never reaching out for global variables, no need to worry about the order in which things get loaded.

So far so good.

But what about dependencies on DOM globals such `window`, `document`, `Node`, etc.?

Is it cool to access these globally? I feel dirty every time I depend on `document.createElement()` for example, without having declared the dependency.

I want to eventually write automated tests for this stuff, I'm assuming I'll have to substitute all of these dependencies with global mocks e.g. under node.js to make the tests pass? Seems like this could turn into a dependency snafu pretty quickly.

What if I were to do the following? e.g. immediately after loading require.js:

```
define("window", function () { return window; });
```

And then explicitly import `window` as a module whenever it's needed:

```
define(["window"], function (window) { .... });
```

Now I should be able to substitute it quite easily.

Of course, I understand this doesn't help with third-party modules the depend on the globals.

Is there any "right" way or best practices to avoid global dependencies in my modules?

Comment: What you suggest is exactly what I was thinking.  Or maybe a "globals":
define("globals", () => { window: window }) to keep it a bit simpler.